# Integration between Salesforce and other systems using existing SAML

Tags: integration, saml

My customer is looking to integrate Salesforce with their external system and is considering authentication options. They already has implemented SAML, using a third-party Identity Provider for integrations between other systems.
They want to leverage their existing SAML integration to connect Salesforce with other internal systems?

Should I make formula fields with HYPERLINK() to external web servers or make an API inbound integration from their external Java client to make it more secure. What do you think should be the correct approach and the reason for your choice?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use SAML connection to call Salesforce web services from the SAML assertion take a peek into the [SAML Assertion Flow for Accessing the Web Services API](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5)

The SAML Assertion flows allow you to use the SAML assertion to exchange for Salesforce access tokens and refresh tokens.

**Coming back to the question of whether HYPERLINK() is more secure or an Inbound HTTP Request?**

HYPERLINK() should be fine as long as you do not pass sensitive data from the formula.

Inbound requests using SSL and HTTPS are secure as data is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks Mohith. I was also inclined towards making inbound request using SSL and HTTPS as that seems more secure than HYPERLINK()